# Where is D3DERR_INVALIDCALL (return code of D3D11CreateDevice) defined?

Tags: c++, direct3d, directx-11, direct3d11

The MSDN documentation says that [D3D11CreateDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns one of the [Direct3D 11 Return Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476174%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Among them is D3DERR_INVALIDCALL. But where is D3DERR_INVALIDCALL defined? Am using the newst Windows SDK. Which header file do I need to include?

Comment: It's defined in `d3d9.h` and also in `d3d9helper.h`.

Comment: Do you know what is the difference between DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL and D3DERR_INVALIDCALL?

Comment: Well, `DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL == 0x887A0001` and `D3DERR_INVALIDCALL == 0x8876086C` if that's what you mean (but I expect not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D3D11CreateDevice always returns one of the D3D11 Return Codes, but it doesn't necessarily return all of them.  D3DERR_INVALIDCALL should never be returned by D3D11CreateDevice since it is a D3D9 error code, and defined only in d3d9.h.

In general, unless you are going to retry the call with different arguments (e.g. by permitting lower feature levels), failing D3D11CreateDevice should be considered an unrecoverable error and you should abort the program.

Comment: D3D11CreateDevice returned DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL on a HD Intel Graphics GPU.

Comment: @Vertexwahn Always take documentation with a grain of salt. It's not always up to date, and sometimes it's just wrong (looks like the latter in this case).  In particular it's difficult to define limits on potential error codes for complex systems like Win32 APIs.  When underlying components fail, APIs have a choice of whether to propagate the error as-is, or re-cast it to its own generic error type.  Propagating is typically the lesser of two evils since it doesn't cause information loss, and the caller might have special knowledge that the intermediate component lacks.